# Set "Prompt users to create a team site under" link in self service site creation management using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, mysite, self-service

[image]I want to set "Prompt users to create a team site under" link in self service site creation management under central admin using Powershell ?

Comment: Can you please add screenshot of the setting?

Comment: Added screenshot for reference.I Want to set this link using PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above code sets link for "Prompt user to create team site under". But its not selected by default.Need to write code as below for link to be set and selected.

```
$web.ShowStartASiteMenuItem=$True
$web.Update()
$web.SelfServiceCreateIndividualSite=$True
$web.SelfServiceCreationParetntSiteUrl = "/relativePath" 
$web.update()
```

Above code sets the link and also make it selected for "Prompt user to create team site under".

Answer (score 2):

Try below PowerShell command for the relative path for the URL:

```
$web.SelfServiceCreationParetntSiteUrl = "/relativePath/[%userid%]"
$web.update();
```

The output will be like below:

[image]

You can visit [this link](http://www.romeodonca.ro/Blog/Post/140/Self-Service-Site-Creation-in-Sharepoint-using-Powershell) for more information on set up User Profile My site using PowerShell.